# lisp reduce heap (array vs list)

Tags: arrays, list, memory, lisp, heap-memory

I made a program in lisp that is increasing the heap way too fast.
The problem should be one of two thing but I'm not sire which one is making the heap grow so fast.
One of them is a list with 15 positions and each position is a structure with 4 field (all fiels are only small numbers)
the other is a 2d array 15x15

Now for every loop cycle I'm making one copy of each using

for the list of structures:
(mapcar #'copy-structure list)

for the 15x15 2d array
(adjust-array
  (make-array dims :displaced-to array)
 dims)

Anyone know which one is the most responsible for the memory consuption?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at this, both will grow the heap on a similar order of magnitude.  I suspect that your algorithm is simply not space efficient enough for your application.

(By the way, use `alexandria:copy-array` for copying arrays.  The `adjust-array` hack is not the most efficient thing to do.)